# Meaning of the composition of functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've a slight curiosity about the composition of functions.

Why the composition of functions is read from right to left?

Example, take 2 functions $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and $g:Z \rightarrow X$, and i make the composition $(f \circ g)(x)$, which is $f(g(\cdot)):Z \rightarrow Y$.
My question is why it isn't simply $g(f(\cdot)):Z \rightarrow Y$, to reading go from left to right...

Comment: Because we write the function argument on the right, $f(x)$, and not on the left, $(x)f$.

Comment: Although there is a way of writing functions on the right: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

Comment: The alternative, functions on the right a la $(x)f$ and $fg$ meaning "do $f$ then $g$", was moderately popular with certain algebraists not too long ago, but it was never widely well-received, and has fallen out of favor. I know Isaacs writes this way, and I'm sure there are others (Hungerford? One of the classic algebra texts; I can't recall)

Comment: Hence than everything depend from the  notation  function's argument, right, in practice by writing the argument to the right, it also affects the composition notation, right?

Comment: There is a perfectly meaningful operator that composes functions in the opposite direction. It's not popular, perhaps because it would break the nice symmetry in the established notation. One problem with the alternative notation would arise when we try to make complex expressions with functions, like $f(x,g(t,h(x,s,q(r))))$. I think this would be quite hard to read in the opposite order. (What do you even write first, $r$ perhaps?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate @DanielFischer's comment: One writes $f \circ g \colon Z \to Y$ for the composition *apply first $g$, then $f$*, to have the following

> $$ (f \circ g)(z) = f\bigl(g(z)\bigr), \quad z \in Z $$
>   read: $f \circ g$ applied to $z$ is $f$ applied to $g(z)$.

So the notation for the composition is motivated from the position of the arguments. If we define $g*f := f \circ g$ (function composition in the other direction), we instead had 
$$ (g * f)(z) = f\bigl(g(z)\bigr) $$
that is applying one of the functions changes the order, what I find hard to read and to remember.

If we write the arguments to the left of the function symbol, that is $(x)f$ instead of $f(x)$, $g*f$ would be the (in my opinion) more natural notation, as in that case
$$ (x)(g*f) = \bigl((x)g\bigr)f $$
gives: first $g$, then $f$.

Comment: Hence in practice, changing the position of argument, change the order of execution, right?

Comment: No, the order of execution in this example is **always** *first $g$, then $f$*, the position of the argument changes the *natural* way for the notation of composition ...

Comment: That is, if change the position of argument, change the reading order in the composition with more functions, right or wrong?